# Powershell If statement not working to validate pgp encryption on file then send file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to PGP encrypt a file then verify if the file is in fact PGP encrypted. Then using an IF, ELSE statement then send the PGP encrypted file. If the file is not PGP encrypted then the file will not be sent. I am trying to make this process fully automated. I write all my code using the PowerShell ISE, then run the code from an application to automate the process. I am not the best coder and I understand some PowerShell but consider myself a noob. Any assistance as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
set-location C:\Scripts\NicksTestScripts

$Datestamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Time = "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}" -f (Get-Date)
$FileGood = "PGP_Test_$Datestamp.txt"
$FileBad = "Not_Encrypted.txt"
$FileGoodPGP = "PGP_Test_$Datestamp.txt.pgp"
$FileBadPGP = "Not_Encrypted.txt.pgp"
$PGPGood = "The $FileGoodPGP is PGP encrypted $Datestamp $Time and has been transferred."
$PGPBad = "The $FileBadPGP is not PGP encrypted $Datestamp $Time and has not been transferred."

pgp --encrypt E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\$FileGood -r "NickW <nwinkel@wilson-mcshane.com>"

Invoke-Expression "pgp --verify 'E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\$FileGoodPGP'" -ErrorVariable PGPError


if($PGPError -like "*input does not contain PGP data*")

{
Remove-Item "E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\$FileGoodPGP"
$PGPBad | Out-File E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_LOG.txt -Append
Exit
}

elseif($PGPError -like "*data is encrypted*")

{
Invoke-Expression "& 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12\wsftppro.exe' -s 'local:E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\$FileGoodPGP' -d 'Shared Sites!NickTest:/PGPTEST/'"
$Fdate = get-date -Format yyyyMMddhhmmssff
Rename-Item -Path "C:\Scripts\Logs\Session Log\WS_FTPSession.log" -NewName "WS_PGP_TEST_$Fdate.log"
Move-Item "C:\Scripts\Logs\Session Log\WS_PGP_TEST_$Fdate.log"  "\\blmnhomebase\c\FTP_Logs"
Remove-Item E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_test_$Datestamp.txt.pgp
$PGPGood | Out-File E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_LOG.txt -Append
Exit(0)
}
```

I get this return when checking the $PGPError variable.

```
pgp : E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_Test_20170918.txt.pgp:verify (3093:data is encrypted to subkey ID 0x78E5104C)
At line:1 char:1
+ pgp --verify E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_Test_20170918.txt.pgp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (E:\LZ\TestAuto\... ID 0x78E5104C):String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_Test_20170918.txt.pgp:verify (3044:subkey ID 0x78E5104C belongs to 0x5FBCDB23 NickW <nwinkel@wilson-mcshane.com>)
E:\LZ\TestAuto\NickTEST\PGP_Test_20170918.txt.pgp:verify (3033:no passphrase specified)
```

Comment: Is pgp.exe writing to the error stream every time?

Comment: Listed $PGPError variable above.

Comment: You need to access the error variable members to actually compare the output.  `$PGPError.Exception.Message`

Comment: I tried that but the script does not use the Out-File nor does it initiate Invoke-Expression either. I am running this job using adTempus application for automation.

Comment: That's because it's never falling into those cases.  Your string comparisons do not match the actual output.

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question but how do I compare the actual output. I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: List the outputs you're **actually** getting from `$PGPError.Exception.Message`